# Saving a Dictionary to .txt file in Scala

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

So I'm training a `xgboost` with hyperparameter tuning. So my code snippet looks something like this:

```
val paramGrid = new ParamGridBuilder().
    addGrid(booster.minChildWeight, Array(0.3,0.6,0.7, 0.8)).
    addGrid(booster.eta, Array(0.1,0.2,0.4, 0.6)).
    build()


val cv = new CrossValidator().
    setEstimator(pipeline).
    setEvaluator(evaluator).
    setEstimatorParamMaps(paramGrid).
    setNumFolds(10)

val cvModel = cv.fit(df)

val bestModel = cvModel.bestModel.asInstanceOf[PipelineModel].stages(1).
    asInstanceOf[XGBoostClassificationModel]
```

Now I want to save the parameter map to a txt and parse it later. However when I'm trying to export it into the text file with something like this:

```
bestModel.extractParamMap()

val file = new File("/home/hadoop/test/hyper_params.txt")
val bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file))
bw.write(bestModel.extractParamMap())
bw.close()
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
error: overloaded method value write with alternatives:
  (x$1: Int)Unit <and>
  (x$1: String)Unit <and>
  (x$1: Array[Char])Unit
 cannot be applied to (org.apache.spark.ml.param.ParamMap)
       bw.write(bestModel.extractParamMap())
```

I'm pretty new to scala and haven't been able to find any solution on how to save the parameter map to a `.txt` file. This is the first step of my problem.

Next I want to create some variables, where in I want to read the saved parameters value from the `.txt` file.

Say something like this:

`val min_child_weight=('../param.txt){key value here}`

So how can I do it? I've gone through some posts like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36437400/how-to-save-a-map-result-to-a-text-file-in-spark-scala) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51281378/error-overloaded-method-value-write-with-alternatives), but haven't been able to figure out the code for my purpose.

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't save stuff in Spark to your local file system using a regular BufferedWriter.  Typically for Dataframes and RDDs, you would use a Spark API and prefix the path the `"file:///"` as shown here - [How to save Spark RDD to local filesystem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40226326/how-to-save-spark-rdd-to-local-filesystem). Also, you would use the `MLWriter` for what you are doing, and you would save the whole Pipeline like so - https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-apache-spark/spark-mllib/spark-mllib-pipelines-persistence.html.

UPDATED:

```
spark
 .sparkContext
 .parallelize(List(bestModel.extractParamMap().toString))
 .saveAsTextFile("file:///home/hadoop/test/hyper_params.txt")
```

Comment: I just want to save the parameter map dictionary. not the entire pipeline, then again from that text file i want to scrape the parameter values.

Comment: I updated it, just put the paramMap into an RDD and wrote to a file

Comment: ok, and do you know how to parse it again from the text file back into my scala program?

Comment: Yeah something like `val dataFrame = sqlContext.read.format("csv").option("delimiter", ":").load("file:///home/hadoop/test/hyper_params.txt")` Dont forget to accept the answer

Comment: bro it got stuck in `saveastextfile` part

Comment: And then when i check, i see `hyper_param.txt` has become a directory